# why different behaviour between ipa and running directly on device

Tags: ios, debugging, release, ipa

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ce72bec8
```

when error like this happens when using ipa, but not run on simulator or directory on device,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ce72bec8
```

when error like this happens when using ipa, but not run on simulator or directory on device, the reason mostly likely is the different optimization level between debug and release